# Why am I getting error "keys.plist" in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I downloaded someone else's code from GitHub, when I try to run it on my computer I'm getting an error "Reading data: the file 'keys.plist' couldn't be opened because there is no such file". I've never seen this before - what does it mean? This file wasn't in the original code, and the project crashes when I delete it.

Comment: That's what happens when you use someone else's code without understanding it.  Since you didn't even provide a project name or link, there's no way to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there should be a "keys.plist" file in the project for it to work.
You should find it